# Limiting theming css files include by store within a module

Tags: magento-1.8, layout

I have a `checkout` module which have a little bit of `new.css` file are there. I want include if `checkout` module is `enabled` other wise no need. Unfortunately, its not include the page in head. if I remove `ifconfig` condition it's working other wise it's not included. 
my code is

**local.xml-> this is not working**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem" ifconfig="checkout/settings/enabled"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/new.css</name></action>
        </reference>
  </default>
```

**local.xml-> this is working**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem" ><type>skin_css</type><name>css/new.css</name></action>
        </reference>
  </default>
```

Can any one tell me where I went wrong?

if checkcout module is enable this file should be include other wise no need.

Comment: have you added `settings` in the config file of `checkout`

Comment: @Helphin, no. Can you post little bit of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code(sample) in the checkout/etc/system.xml inside the groups,

```
            <settings translate="label">
                <fields>
                    <enabled translate="label">
                        <label>Enabled</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </enabled>
                <fields>    
            <settings>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.